# Tables in Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I am trying to create a financial program where all transactions from several users will be stored in a MS Access DB.  Now my question is: which is more efficient?  Storing all transactions in one table, or to create a table for each user?  Please note that each user could have thousands of transactions over several years

Thanks

Comment: "Now my question is: which is more efficient? Storing all transactions in one table, or to create a table for each user? " - you are asking the wrong question. It's not a question of efficiency, rather one of correct design. And the answer is almost certainly one table.

Comment: But why?  I understand what you are saying, but will the table not use more space/processing power when all the records are posted to one table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One table. You will run into trouble managing individual tables for the users - sooner or later.

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  Exactly the answer I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a front end database and a backend database.  This will allow you to make changes to the front end without the risk of damaging the backend database.  While this may seem like extra work, in the long run, assuming this database will be used for more than a few months, the database will be more modular and easier to manage going forward.  This also provides access to the database to more than a single user as the temporary files that are created will not lock the table as they are updated or changed.  Concurrency is always something to consider when creating a new database.

Comment: I like the idea that you are giving.  But the program will only accommodate one person at a time.  But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**One table** for sure.

One out of many reasons for that is, you need to create a new table for every new single users and change all the related aliases of your `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `SELECT` statements regarding your new table name.

[Designing databases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187099(v=sql.105).aspx)